# Gesture listener on a dialog

Tags: android, gesture

I've found a few examples of the `GestureListener` but it's always on a `Activty`, I've got a `ListView` on my `Activity` and I've created a `dialog` for the gestures but cant get it to work

These are the examples I'm using as a starting point
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html
http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/tag/gesture-builder/

and that's what i need but for custom gestures

[Android onTouchListener for entire dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848269/android-ontouchlistener-for-entire-dialog)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

so did some more googling and found an easier way, found this very useful example on the android developers website

http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2009/10/gestures-on-android-16.html

so i've got a gesture view as an overlay of a regular ListView.