# Zoom Dialog in Android

Tags: android, dialog, rotation, zooming, drag

How does one apply **zoom in, zoom out, drag and rotate** gestures on **Dialog** in Android. I have tried using `ScaleGestureDetector` but without luck.

I have searched a lot but I am only getting results related to imageview and layouts.

Comment: create a custom layout open it as a dailog and apply on it

Comment: any other option with Dialog itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the activity to wrap a dialog.And you can use the activity zoom in or zoom out and so on.

The dialog is like this:

```
public class MessageBackDialog extends Activity {

// 提交按钮
private Button commitBtn;

// commentID
private String commentID;

// 当前的类型
private String type;

// appID
private String appID;

// 测试加载对话框
private LoadingDialog ld;

private DownLoadEventNotifier den;

// 编辑评论
private EditText et_text_reply;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_reply_layout);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    type = intent.getStringExtra("TYPE");

    if (type.equals("BACK")) {
        commentID = intent.getStringExtra("CID");
    } else {
        appID = intent.getStringExtra("AID");
    }

    initView();
    setListener();
}

private void initView() {
    ld = LoadingDialog.createDialog(getApplicationContext());

    et_text_reply = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_text_reply);
    commitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_commit);

    den = new DownLoadEventNotifier(new DownInterface() {

        @Override
        public void onDownloadSuccess(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}

private void setListener() {
    commitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: i have to use dialog only as every thing is done perfectly in that.Only zoom and all gestures are remaining . Don't have that much time to change everything done previously.

Comment: You don't need to do more things to change the dialog to activity!

Comment: but my dialog doesn't cover whole screen,is that possible using activity dialog?

Comment: Yes,This activity also doesn't cover the whole screen.You can give me your email that I post my demo to you

Comment: Please wait a minutes!

Comment: I have been sent the email.You can change the animation in the style.xml file!

Comment: i haven't got any mail till now

Comment: It's back,I don't know why,I will send it again.

Comment: Give you a url,You download it yourself.I don't know why I can not send you a email.  This is the url "http://1drv.ms/1WPhonc"

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class which extends the dialog class and then you can create a gesture detector and attach to the ontouchevent of the class.

Here is a code example, taken from refer here [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12073651/5456493):

> ```
> public class GestureDialog extends Dialog {
>   public GestureDialog (Context context, int theme) {
>       super(context, theme);
>
>       gestDetec = new MyGestureDetector();    //inital setup
>         gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(gestDetec); 
>         gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
>             public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
>                 if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
>                     return true;
>                 }
>                 return false;
>             }
>         };
>   }
>   @Override
>     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
>         if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
>           return true;
>       else
>           return false;
>     }
> class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
>   @Override
>   public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
>
>       System.out.println( "Help im being touched!" );
>       return false;
>   }
> }
>
> }
> ```